# In-text quotation capitalization?

Tags: quotation

When directly citing a heading of a source - such as "Nature of services" - do you keep the capitalization (as just presented) or do it as the following with squared brackets, stating "[n]ature of services"?

PS: Original source is -> Nature of services

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should titles in the references be in title case?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61089/should-titles-in-the-references-be-in-title-case)

Comment: No. I am talking about in-text referencing.

Answer (score 1):

"*[n]ature of services*" is a suitable direct citation.
The `[]` indicate that you are repurposing the original to suit the flow of your sentence/paragraph.

AFAIK, it's not overly frowned at in law, humanities, information systems. However, some universities or journals might request you do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a quote should be exact, but for a snippet, as in your example, a modification is probably ok, especially since it is specifically noted that it has been modified.

Clarity is the most important thing.

Comment: So you recommend doing "[nature] of services"?

Comment: Not really. "[n]ature..." makes it clearer what the edit was, actually. [nature] is ambiguous.