# Uppercase/lowercase paper titles on a CV

Tags: publications, conference, cv

I have two papers from different conferences. The first has a title with all words beginning with an upper case letter. The second has a title with only the first letter of the first word capitalized.

On a CV, would it be acceptable to write both paper titles in the same uppercase/lowercase format, for consistency? Or should the CV titles be exactly as they appear on the papers?

Comment: Oh, the joys of languages with variable capitalization rules ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my citation style exactly match the original title?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46526/should-my-citation-style-exactly-match-the-original-title)

Comment: Lucky you, that you don't have a paper where all letters in the title are capitals.

Comment: It doesn't matter. But, you must follow consistency.

Answer (score 8):

Formatting of titles in citations is specified by citation style guides, [APA, for example](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/how-to-capitalize-and-format-reference-titles-in-apa-style.html) and depends on the context. If you are formatting your CV in APA style, you would use the link I provided and use "sentence case" for both titles (capitalize first word only) in your CV.

Note that this does not depend on the capitalization of the title in the original source; you should consider the title capitalization to be a formatting issue which will vary across formatting schemes but should be standardized when you bring the works together, like in a references list or CV.

This goes for English capitalization rules; I am not aware of APA guidelines for citations in other languages, such as German, which use different capitalization. Without further guidance, I would just suggest to be consistent.